# How to debug the error "The requested property 'current-activity' is not available"?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

My Project is using IBM ClearCase as version control tool. I recently checked in some of the files, modified them and even checked out the modified files.

Next day when I try to check in some of the files, I am getting the following error :

```
the property is not available locally: stream
```

and

```
 the property is not available locally: current-activity
```

Is there any way to resolve this error? I am stuck

Comment: Run ClearCase Doctor and see what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I recently checked in some of the files, modified them and even checked out the modified files.

You actually checked out files, then modify them, then check them in.
You check out in order to make a file modifiable.

```
 the property is not available locally: current-activity
```

The exact error message is actually:

```
 The requested property 'current-activity' is not available
```

See this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449554):

> #### Cause
>
> 1. The information within the .Rational folder had become stale or corrupted.
> 2. ClearQuest database connections require refreshing as they are no longer seen.
> 3. View tag (as stored in the registry server) is no longer visible on the Change Management (CM) Server when performing an Cleartool lsview.
> 4. This issue can also occur if the region used does not hold the right VOBs any longer. While trying to create new Views or change load rules the VOBs are missing. This happened due to a changed region map file.

So it depends on your OS, version of ClearCase, integration or not with clearquest.

Comment: Yes. u were right. The view was deleted and thats why i am getting this error.